# Posting JSON string to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Okay, I'm having some suicidal issues posting a JSON string to a PHP page. I have literally been through the top ten results on Google and plenty of SO questions related to my problem, but still can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

I have multiple forms on a page and want to collect all form fields, turn them into a JSON string and post them to a PHP page, where a script iterates each item and updates the relevant database tables.

This is my jQuery/JS script to collect the data from all the forms:

var photo_annotations = {};

```
$('form').each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    photo_annotations[id] = {
        caption: $('#'+id+'_caption').val(),
        keywords: $('#'+id+'_keywords').val(),
        credit: $('#'+id+'_credit').val(),
        credit_url: $('#'+id+'_credit_url').val()
    };
});
```

If I `console.log` my photo_annotations object, this is what is produced, based on a two form example:

> ({11:{caption:"Caption for first photo.", keywords:"Keyword1,
>   Keyword2, Keyword3", credit:"Joe Bloggs",
>   credit_url:"www.a-domain.com"}, 12:{caption:"Caption for Lady Gaga.",
>   keywords:"Keyword3, Keyword4", credit:"John Doe",
>   credit_url:"www.another-domain.com"}})

I then need to POST this as a string/JSON to a PHP page, so I've done this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'ajax/save-annotations.php',
    data: { data: JSON.stringify(photo_annotations) },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
        $('#form_results').html(data);
        } else {
        alert("No data");   
        }
    }
});
```

And on my PHP page, I've got this:

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST['data']);
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
print_r($decoded);
?>
```

Now, this isn't the only thing I've tried. I've tried to remove all the JSON settings from the AJAX script, in a bid to just send a pure string. I've tried removing contentType and JSON.stringify but still won't go. My PHP page just can't get the data that I'm sending.

Please help push me in the right direction. I've got to the point where I can't remember all the variations I've tried and this little script is now on day 2!

**MANAGED TO FIX IT**

I rewrote my AJAX function and it worked. I have no idea what was going wrong but decided to test my AJAX function with a very basic data string `test=hello world` and found that no POST data could be read from the PHP page, even though Firebug says that the page did in fact receive post data matching what I sent. Very strange. Anyway, this is the revised AJAX script:

```
var the_obj = JSON.stringify(photo_annotations);
var post_data = "annotations="+the_obj;
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/save-annotations',
    type: 'POST',
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#form_results').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the HTML dataType?

Comment: Because I'm sending HTML back from the PHP page when the processing of the data is complete. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, no it is. Sorry, misread your code. I did not realize that you were decoding the posted data. HTML would be the correct dataType then, yes.

Comment: Is there as special reason why you would want to send the data as JSON and process it as such – instead of sending it the “normal” way?

Comment: @CBroe: That all depends on what the 'normal' way is :P I suppose there is no specific reason why I want to use JSON, I just want to send all the forms data in an understandable format to process on another page. My previous attempt was to loop through each form and post the data with AJAX, but if I have 30 images on a page, that meant 30 AJAX request and 30 SQL updates, which is not good. I just want to post one request and have one SQL query.

Comment: Well, “normal” would be `application/x-www-form- urlencoded`, the same that your browser uses when submitting a form natively. And why do you have multiple forms, if you want to send the data in one go? Anyway, using jQuery’s `serialize` you should be able to serialize the data of multiple forms as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    data: { data: JSON.stringify(photo_annotations) },
    // ...
  });
```

If you just set the "data" property to a string, then jQuery thinks you want to use it as the actual query string, and that clearly won't work when it's a blob of JSON.  When you pass jQuery an *object*, as above, then it'll do the appropriate URL-encoding of the property names and values (your JSON blob) and create the query string for you. You should get a single "data" parameter at the server, and it's value will be the JSON string.

Comment: I just tried this and hasn't changed anything. Well, it may have, as I can confirm that I'm getting some data sent to the server in an object called 'data' and contains stuff like this: data=%7B%2211%22%3A%7B%22caption%22%3A%22%22%2C%22keywords%22%3A%22%22%2C%22credit%22%3A%22%22%2C%22credit_url%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%2212%22%3A%7B%22caption%22%3A%22%...

Comment: Is that format above correct? I'm thinking it's more of a problem with PHP now, as I know my PHP page is getting some data but can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) or [rawurldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) as follows:

```
<?php
$decoded = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['data']), true);
print_r($decoded);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my AJAX function and it now works. I have no idea what was going wrong but decided to test my AJAX function with a very basic data string `test=hello world` and found that no POST data could be read from the PHP page, even though Firebug says that the page did in fact receive post data matching what I sent. Very strange. Anyway, this is the revised AJAX script:

```
var the_obj = JSON.stringify(photo_annotations);
var post_data = "annotations="+the_obj;
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/save-annotations',
    type: 'POST',
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#form_results').html(data);
    }
});
```

The only thing I can think of is that the order of AJAX settings needed to be in a particular order. This is my old AJAX script which does not send POST data successfully - well it does send, but cannot be read!!

```
var the_obj = JSON.stringify(photo_annotations);
var data_str = "annotations="+the_obj;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: data_str,
    url: 'ajax/save-annotations.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#form_results').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax call try resetting the dataType to json

```
dataType: "json",
```

You wouldn't have to use the JSON.stringify() either. On your php script you won't have to decode [json_decode()] the data from the $_POST variable. The data will be easy readable by your php script.