# Post object as JSON and retrieve in PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I'm thinking my situation is a bit different.

I want to send a JS-object with jQuery.ajax to my PHP-server, so I did:

**Clientside**

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl+"?action=slFnc",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function(data) {

        showMessage(1,data);

    },
    error: function(req, status, error){
        showMessage(3,req.statusText);
    }
});
```

**Serverside:**

```
saveData($_POST['obj'])
function saveData($obj]){

    json_decode($obj);

}
```

I know that "obj" is not set in $_POST, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why you want to pass json only ?  when you can pass single array of data like :

data: {
            obj: obj
        },

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802077/posting-json-string-to-php-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { obj:JSON.stringify(obj)}
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
  });
```

php:

```
$obj=json_decode($_POST['obj']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:"script.php",
               data: "obj="+JSON.stringify(obj),
               dataType: 'JSON',
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
               }
        });
```

In php file

```
      <?php

         if(isset($_POST['obj'])){

                $obj=json_decode($_POST['obj']);
         }

       ?>
```